# Should mongodb be run in a service, or a worker cluster?

Tags: mongodb, configuration

I'm trying to implement an architecture that's similar to the coreos's production architecture (shown below)

[image]

Should I run the database as a central service or one or more of the workers?

I figured the database needs some kind of replication, which makes me think that putting it in the worker cluster makes more sense, but I'm just not sure.